# Is it possible to break `case xx : {` into two line with AStyle?

Tags: format, astyle

I need to format following code

```
switch(i) {
    case 1: {
            printf("a");
            break;
        }
```

into:

```
switch(i) {
    case 1: 
        {
            printf("a");
            break;
        }
```

with keeping the k&r bracket style on other situations. How could I do this?

I have tried `--style=kr --indent-cases`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regex to replace:

```
s/\(case.*:\s\+\){/\1\r{/g
```